# Why cant i sync my project in Android Studio?

Tags: android, synchronization

I wanted to learn how to make android apps and downloaded android studio.
But when I made my first project and it was trying to sync an error came. This is what it said: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'. 
When i went to Android Manifest most of it was red. Does someone know what to do?

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.oliver.mycart">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:abel="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".Menu"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Did you install latest Android tools and SDK?

Comment: I downloaded a few days ago. The version I'm using is 3.2

Answer (score 1):

```
  android:abel="@string/app_name"
```

you have error in this line. Try to change *abel* to *label*